# Empty Nuget package for just dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a project I'd like to put all my dependencies into one nuget package.  The idea is that when I need to I can just pull in that one nuget package instead of 10 that I require.  Is this possible to do?

When I created a library I removed the class file and just pulled in the dependencies but could not get a package to create.

Comment: Why does this matter?  Your project will pull everything in your packages config, just put all your dependencies in there and let nuget do its job.  Or are you asking how to create a nuget package out of a class library that you yourself have created?

Comment: also, that strategy denies you notifications when dependent packages get updated.  You're essentially hitting pause.

Comment: These would be packages that I have created.  So i'd know when they are updated. I was trying to create a cleaner packages config, but if it imports them anyways and not just the single package with its dependencies, then this is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `IncludeBuildOutput` property to `false` while creating the package.

For example [using VS 2017] -

1. File > New Project > .NET Core class library
2. Right click on project and edit csproj to have the following content -

> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
>     <PackageId>MetaPackage</PackageId>
>     <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
>     <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
>     <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Versioning" Version="4.7.0-rtm.5104" />
>     <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.10.1" />
>   </ItemGroup>
>
> </Project>
> ```

3. Right click and build project
4. Look at the package at `<project_dir>\bin\Debug\MetaPackage.1.0.0.nupkg`

This will create a package that has no `\lib` and the nuspec file should have package reference dependencies.

You can read more about `IncludeBuildOutput` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#includebuildoutput).

Comment: Note that solution now causes "  NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221, 5): [NU5128] Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
- Add lib or ref assemblies for the netstandard2.0 target framework"
Also the docs on IncludeBuildOutput have disappeared.